# What is the path for solving $(20! \cdot 12!) \bmod 2012$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, factorial

I cannot solve this question: $(20! \cdot 12!) \bmod 2012$. I have tried finding the divisors but $2012$ equals $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 503$. $503$ is a prime number and I am stuck.

Comment: Maybe you just have to do it the old-fashioned way. Multiply and modulo, one number at a time.

Comment: Turns out that $504 = 2^3*3^2*7$. That might help, along with some CRT

Comment: @John Lou thank you for the explanation but English is not my main language. Could you explain crt please?

Comment: It's the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Comment: Following John Lou's hint, factorize $20!$ and $12!$ into prime powers. This is not so difficult ( for example, $11$ shows up just twice, and $13,17$ and $19$ show up once each).

Comment: Two useful facts:  John Lou's hint shows that $7^{-1} \equiv 72 \equiv 2^3 3^2 \pmod{503}.$  That can be helpful using the hint, because one runs out of $7$'s.  Second, and there's something I don't get here, but if there is a trick to the problem, it must lie in the fact that $20!12! \equiv 13\cdot 17\cdot 19 \pmod{503}$.  That is, the product of all the prime factors which occur only once.

Comment: 1684 is the answer